# Reading MONO 16-bit images using PyCapture2

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the `CMLN-13S2M-CS` camera from PointGrey. This camera has a MONO 16-bit pixel format.Using the `PyCapture2` wrapper from PointGrey I am unable to retrieve the image the camera is recording.

I have the following code:

```
import sys
import numpy
import PyCapture2

## Connect camera
bus = PyCapture2.BusManager()
c = PyCapture2.Camera()
c.connect(bus.getCameraFromIndex(0))

## Configure camera format7 settings
fmt7imgSet = PyCapture2.Format7ImageSettings(0, 0, 0, 1296, 964, PyCapture2.PIXEL_FORMAT.MONO16)
fmt7pktInf, isValid = c.validateFormat7Settings(fmt7imgSet)
c.setFormat7ConfigurationPacket(fmt7pktInf.recommendedBytesPerPacket, fmt7imgSet)

## Start capture and retrieve buffer
c.startCapture()
im = c.retrieveBuffer()

print im.getData().shape
print numpy.max(im.getData())
```

The following is returned by the `print` statements: `(2498688,)` and `240`. The shape is exactly `2 x (964 x 1296)`. How should I reshape this? Also, the maximum value when saturated is `255`. This is odd as this corresponds to MONO 8 Pixel format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like `im.getData()` returns a 1D array of 8 bit data. So that needs to be converted to a 2D array of 16 bit integers. What's the dtype of `im.getData()`? I suspect it's `uint8`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The `dtype` of `im.getData()` is `uint8`. How would I go about converting/reshaping it to a 2D array of 16 bit integers?

Comment: Numpy can easily do the required conversion, you just need to know how the data is organized. I _assume_ that it's something straightforward, eg 2 adjacent bytes make a pixel, 1296 pixels make a row, but you might need to do a little trial & error to determine the actual data layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick demo that shows how to convert a 1D array of `uint8` to a 2D array of `uint16`. The key function we need here is [`view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view).

```
import numpy as np

# Make 24 bytes of fake data
raw = np.arange(24, dtype=np.uint8)

#Convert
out = raw.view(np.uint16).reshape(3, 4)
print(out)
print(out.dtype)
```

**output**

```
[[ 256  770 1284 1798]
 [2312 2826 3340 3854]
 [4368 4882 5396 5910]]
uint16
```

Thanks to Andras Deak for his assistance!

If the resulting image doesn't look correct, you may need to swap the byte ordering of the 16 bit integers. You can read about byte ordering in Numpy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.byteswapping.html).

And if *that* still doesn't look correct, then the data may be organized as two planes, with one plane for the low-order bits of a pixel and the other plane for the high-order bits. That's also easy to deal with, but hopefully it won't come to that. ;)